# Collision issue when too many objects on the screen

Tags: javascript

I am using the following function to create the bullet (while player keeps ctrl) and place it into an array called bullets:

```
setInterval(function produceBullet() {
if (shoot) {
    bullet = new Bullet(player.x - 3, player.y - 3, 6, 16, 10)
    bullets.push(bullet);
}
}, 200);
```

The next function is about collision between boss and bullets. In that case each bullet takes 1 life from the boss (number on top of the game):

```
function collisions() {
for (i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
    if (bullet.x > bossOne.x && bullet.x < bossOne.x + bossOne.sizeX &&
        bullet.y < bossOne.y + bossOne.sizeY && bullet.y > bossOne.y) {
        bullets.splice(i, 1);
        bossLife -= 1;
        bossLifeCounter.innerHTML = bossLife;
        if (bossLife <= 0) {
            bossLifeCounter.innerHTML = "winner!";
            bossOne.x = -10000;
        }
    }
}  
}
```

I use also show function:

```
function draw() {
for (i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
    bullets[i].show();
    bullets[i].move();
    if (bullet.y < 0) {
        bullets.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

collisions();

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Everything is fine when there is only 1 bullet on the screen, player keeps the ctrl to shoot the boss and he's losing his life without releasing ctrl.

The problem is when player is far away from the boss, so there are many bullets on the screen and collision works only, when the ctrl key is released.

Full code on remote server, where you can inspect the problem: https://stacho163.000webhostapp.com/

If anybody has time to look into the code (it's short and i think clear) and has an idea what's wrong with it i would be grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the intersection observer api, it will give you much better performace than rolling your own collision detection.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look, but that's not a problem with the collision itself as it's working for single object very well. Array of bullets somehow blocks the collision execution on time, but i can't figure out why it's happening. It's waiting with collision till player stop producing bullets (stop holding ctrl)